QGIS EnMap-Box3 not giving wavelength values
I am using EnMap-Box 3 in QGIS to collect spectral values and create a spectral libraries I can create a .sli file and when i look at the .hdr file the wavelength is missing. When i export the spectral library as .sli file there is an option profile values and Name. If i enter Name then the spectra name in the hdr file is filled with the name of the individual profile.And if i select Profiles then the Spectra name is filled with some binary values.
How can i extract wavelength and the spectral values in my .sli files.
Steps i took to collect spectral profile.
Add data source- select a raster.
Then right click on the image and click open in new map.
Then i click on identify pixel profiles and show them in a Spectral library.
I select add profile automatically then i select some pixel



